# backing up Linux (CentOS) to rsync.net

Tags: linux, centos, rsync

I'm doing a full backup of a server using /usr/bin/rsync and it seemed to hang.  The problem was that the /proc directory has a huge file

> -r--------   1 root     root     140737477877760 Jan 24 13:54 kcore

What is that?  Is there anything in the /proc directory that I really need?

Are there other directories that can be omitted?

Comment: I suppose you can skip it: _"kcore file is only a virtual file. It contains the RAM the kernel can allocate."_ [see here](https://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=7004153) for example... and search more fonts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading from <sup>[[1](http://www.unixguide.net/linux/faq/04.16.shtml)]</sup>

> None of the files in /proc are really there--they're all, "pretend,"
>   files made up by the kernel, to give you information about the system
>   and don't take up any hard disk space.
>
> /proc/kcore is like an "alias" for the memory in your computer. Its
>   size is the same as the amount of RAM you have, and if you read it as
>   a file, the kernel does memory reads.

Moreover it is reported to show a size bigger than the physical memory installed on the computer and (it is reported to be able to) arrive to result as big as the memory addressable (128TB!). <sup>[[2](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=88523)]</sup>

> I have seen a few places on the web that say it is actually the size of the maximum memory mapping of the system, so for my arch-64 system it is 128TB! Of course, it really isn't a "size", just a view.

it seems you have really to skip it in a backup :-)